# How to use sort="auto" on A object?

Tags: groovy, zk, zul

I have a listheader element with sort="auto" set, but when I click the column, the list doesn't sort. The arrows appear and reverse direction, but the list order doesn't change.

The Components appended to the list are `org.zkoss.zul.A` objects, which appears to be the reason sorting does not work.

Is there a workaround to get sorting to work for a Listbox whose list items are A objects?

my zul:

```
<listbox id="myList" checkmark="true" multiple="true">
  <listhead>
    <listheader id='select' label="" width="30px" align="left"/>
    <listheader label="myLabel" width="75px" sort="auto"/>
  </listhead>
</listbox>
```

groovy:

```
Listitem li = new Listitem(value: "myId")
li.appendChild(new Listcell())
Listcell listcell = new Listcell()
Long theId = "12345"
A link = new A(label: theId.toString(), style: "color:blue;")
listcell.appendChild(invoiceLink)
li.appendChild(listcell)
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete, or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'am using MVVM approach and this is how I sort my listbox

```
<listbox>
     <listhead>
        <listheader label="Hopper" width="60px" sort="auto(hopperCode)" />
        <listheader label="Stop Time" width="80px" sort="auto(startTime)" />
    </listhead>
    <template name="model">
        <listitem>
            <listcell label="@load(each.hopperCode)" />
            <listcell label="@load(each.startTime)" />
        </listitem>
    </template>
</listbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this paragraph in the documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Listbox#Sorting), sort auto sorts by **the label of the listcell**. You are not using `Listcell.setLabel()`, but append an `A` component to it. Since the listcells' labels are all the same (i.e. ""), sorting doesn't do anything.

Try [setting custom comparators](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Listbox#The_SortAscending_and_SortDescending_Properties).  For this purpose I advise using a model instead of creating the listitems yourself.